# How to launch ant clean target when executing eclipse Project clean

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

In order to simplify Eclipse use for our newbie users, we want to add this features to Eclipse :

1) If the user click on Project ---->Clean... , eclipse launches also the ant clean target which is implemented in the build.xml file of the concerned project.

2) When the user saves the code, the ant build is launched automatically.

Any link or a starting point. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an Ant build file to the builders for a project in project `Properties > Builders`. Click `New...` and select `Ant Builder`. You can then specify the build.xml and select the targets used for clean, manual build and auto build (run during save).